# redis save return (error) ERR, no info in log

Tags: redis

running

```
save
```

returns

```
(error) ERR
```

/var/log/redis/redis-server.log is empty

```
bgsave
```

returns

```
Background saving started
```

but

```
lastsave
```

shows old date (date of install I suppose)

Where can I find out more details about these errors?

Comment: `BGSAVE` returning anything in the log ?

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab nothing

Answer (score 0):

1 If not root, check if current user has write access to rdb directory.

2 Modify redis.conf, set logfile to "", force log on the console. (daemonize shoule be no).

Comment: there is a lot of space